# Spring Data JPA - for loop not saving entity

Tags: java, hibernate, for-loop, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to save multiple strings into one column into MySQL DB. Using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate.

I have my `PersonserviceImpl` as

```
    @Override
public void createnewPerson(AppPerson appPerson) {

    List<AppPersonproperty> personProperties = personpropertyRepository
            .findByPersonid(appPerson.getAppPersontype().getId());

        for (AppPersonproperty app : personProperties) {
            System.out.println(app.getPersonpropertyname());
            entity.setPersonpropertyname(app.getPersonpropertyname());
        }

    personRepository.save(entity);
}
```

Only the last value gets save from Person's previous names.

Sysout:

```
SpiderMan
Spidey
```

Expected value in the column:

```
SpiderManSpidey
```

Actual value in the column:

```
Spidey
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would JPA append `String`s in a column when you are replacing them on the Java side?

If you want them appended in the column you need to append them on the Java side as well.
Replacing

```
entity.setPersonpropertyname(app.getPersonpropertyname());
```

with

```
entity.setPersonpropertyname(entity.getPersonpropertyname() + app.getPersonpropertyname());
```

should do the trick.

Comment: What a dumbo I am.! . Yes you are right Jens. Your trick is working.!!